# How to fetch firebase realtime database firebase in my flutter chat app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
Stream<List<Message>> getChatStream(String recieverUserId) {
    return firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection('quickgramchats')
        .doc(recieverUserId)
        .collection('messages')
        .orderBy('timeSent', descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map(
      (event) {
        List<Message> messages = [];

        for (var document in event.docs) {
          messages.add(Message.fromMap(document.data()));
        }

        log('1$messages');

        return messages;
      },
    );
  }



Stream<List<Message>> chatStream(String recieverUserId) {
    return chatRepository.getChatStream(recieverUserId);
  }


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Message>>(
      stream:
          ref.read(chatControllerProvider).chatStream(widget.recieverUserId),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Loader();
        }

        final messages = snapshot.data!;
        chatWithHeaders.clear();
        DateTime? currentDate;

        final DateTime now = DateTime.now();

        for (int i = messages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          final messageData = messages[i];
          if (!messageData.isSeen &&
              messageData.recieverid ==
                  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid) {
            ref.read(chatControllerProvider).setChatMessageSeen(
                context, widget.recieverUserId, messageData.messageId);
          }

          if (currentDate == null ||
              !isSameDay(messageData.timeSent, currentDate)) {
            // Add a new date header if it's a new day
            if (isSameDay(messageData.timeSent, now)) {
              // Display "Today" instead of the actual date
              chatWithHeaders.add("  Today  ");
            } else if (isSameDay(
                messageData.timeSent, now.subtract(const Duration(days: 1)))) {
              // Display "Yesterday" instead of the actual date
              chatWithHeaders.add("Yesterday");
            } else {
              // Display the actual date
              chatWithHeaders
                  .add(DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy').format(messageData.timeSent));
              // Update the current date
            }
            currentDate = messageData.timeSent;
          }
          chatWithHeaders.add(messageData);
        }

        // The messages themselves are in reversed order, reverse the chatWithHeaders list
        chatWithHeaders = chatWithHeaders.reversed.toList();

        return ListView.builder(
          reverse: true,
          itemCount: chatWithHeaders.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final chatItem = chatWithHeaders[index];

            if (chatItem is String) {
              // Display timestamp header
              return Center(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 195, 212, 222),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(chatItem),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else if (chatItem is Message) {
              // Display chat message
              var timeSent = DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(chatItem.timeSent);
              var sentTime =
                  chatItem.timeSent.toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

              final fromMeID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

              final haveNip = (index == 0) ||
                  (index == snapshot.data!.length - 1 &&
                      fromMeID != snapshot.data![index - 1].senderId) ||
                  (fromMeID != snapshot.data![index - 1].senderId &&
                      fromMeID == snapshot.data![index + 1].senderId) ||
                  (fromMeID != snapshot.data![index - 1].senderId &&
                      fromMeID != snapshot.data![index + 1].senderId);

              if (chatItem.senderId == FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid) {
                return MyMessageCard(
                  message: chatItem.text,
                  date: timeSent,
                  sentTime: sentTime,
                  type: chatItem.type,
                  recieverUserId: chatItem.recieverid,
                  messageId: chatItem.messageId,
                  read: chatItem.read,
                  repliedText: chatItem.repliedMessage,
                  username: chatItem.repliedTo,
                  repliedMessageType: chatItem.repliedMessageType,
                  onLeftSwipe: () =>
                      onMessageSwipe(chatItem.text, true, chatItem.type),
                  isSeen: chatItem.isSeen,
                  haveNip: haveNip,
                  isSender: true,
                );
              } else {
                return SenderMessageCard(
                  message: chatItem.text,
                  date: timeSent,
                  sentTime: sentTime,
                  read: chatItem.read,
                  senderUserId: chatItem.senderId,
                  messageId: chatItem.messageId,
                  type: chatItem.type,
                  username: chatItem.repliedTo,
                  repliedMessageType: chatItem.repliedMessageType,
                  onRightSwipe: () =>
                      onMessageSwipe(chatItem.text, false, chatItem.type),
                  repliedText: chatItem.repliedMessage,
                );
              }
            } else {
              return const SizedBox.shrink(); // Handle other cases if needed
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );



import 'package:quick_gram/common/enums/message_enum.dart';

class Message {
  final String senderId;
  final String recieverid;
  final String text;
  final MessageEnum type;
  final DateTime timeSent;
  final String messageId;
  final bool isSeen;
  final String repliedMessage;
  final String repliedTo;
  final MessageEnum repliedMessageType;
  late final String read;
  late final bool isEdit;

  Message({
    required this.senderId,
    required this.recieverid,
    required this.text,
    required this.type,
    required this.timeSent,
    required this.messageId,
    required this.isSeen,
    required this.repliedMessage,
    required this.repliedTo,
    required this.repliedMessageType,
    required this.read,
    required this.isEdit,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'senderId': senderId,
      'recieverid': recieverid,
      'text': text,
      'type': type.type,
      'timeSent': timeSent.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      'messageId': messageId,
      'isSeen': isSeen,
      'isEdit': isEdit,
      'repliedMessage': repliedMessage,
      'repliedTo': repliedTo,
      'repliedMessageType': repliedMessageType.type,
      'read': read,
    };
  }

  factory Message.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Message(
      senderId: map['senderId'] ?? '',
      recieverid: map['recieverid'] ?? '',
      text: map['text'] ?? '',
      type: (map['type'] as String).toEnum(),
      timeSent: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['timeSent']),
      messageId: map['messageId'] ?? '',
      isSeen: map['isSeen'] ?? false,
      isEdit: map['isEdit'] ?? false,
      repliedMessage: map['repliedMessage'] ?? '',
      repliedTo: map['repliedTo'] ?? '',
      repliedMessageType: (map['repliedMessageType'] as String).toEnum(),
      read: map['read'] ?? '',
    );
  }
}
```

I have been using firebase firestore, but now i changed my Firestore to Realtime database.
I am not able  change the `getChatStream` to works with realtime database.

I need to fetch them from realtime database, and show them:

[image]

Comment: Both databases are quite well documented, so I recommend starting with https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/start and giving it a try. If you get stuck on a specific step in the conversion, post back and we're more likely to be able to help.

Comment: Ok, I will read the documentation and give it try at my own

Comment: I understand nothing,, I am using firestore for long time i know how to work with firestore

can you help me in my above code???

Comment: i did it my own......

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @Quickgram  --- Consider posting your solution below, so that others can benefit from it.